# abstract class program providing LNK1169 error

Tags: c++, virtual, abstract, void

I'm working on a cpp programm using abstract classes. Apparently the compiler doesn't accept the fact that I declared the abstract class and the derived. I have different files (.cpp and .h). The errors are the following:

1>IGeomObj.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual void __thiscall IGeomObj::circumference(void)" (?circumference@IGeomObj@@UAEXXZ) already defined in GeoRect.obj

1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall GeoRect::circumference(void)" (?circumference@GeoRect@@UAEXXZ)

1>IGeomObj.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

And here the code:
main()

```
 # include <iostream>
 # include "IGeomObj.h"
 # include "GeoCircle.h"
 # include "GeoEllipse.h"
 # include "GeoRect.h"
 # include "GeoSquare.h"
 # include "GeoTriangle.h"

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
/*GeoSquare *R;
GeoTriangle *R;
GeoRect *R;
GeoRect *R;*/
int opt;
do{
    cout<<endl<<"Menu:"<<endl<<endl<<"0.    Exit"<<endl<<"1.    New rectangle"
        <<endl<<"2. New Square"<<endl<<"3.  New Triangle"<<endl<<"4.    New        Circle"<<endl
        <<"5.   New Ellipse"<<endl;
        cin>>opt;
    switch(opt)
    {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        GeoRect *R=new GeoRect;
        cout<<endl<<"Height of the rectangle: ";
        cin>>R->h;
        cout<<endl<<"Width of the rectangle: ";
        cin>>R->b;
        R->output();
        break;

    };
}while(opt!=0);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

IGeomObj.h

```
 #pragma once
 #ifndef IGEOMOBJ_H
 #define IGEOMOBJ_H

 #include <iomanip>
 #include <fstream>

 class IGeomObj{

 public:

float b,h,r,f,u;
virtual void output()=0;
virtual void area()=0;
virtual void circumference()=0;
};
#endif
```

IGeomObj.cpp

```
 #include "IGeomObj.h"
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 void IGeomObj::output(){};
 void IGeomObj::area(){};
 void IGeomObj::circumference(){};
```

GeoRect.h

```
 #pragma once
 #ifndef GEORECT_H
 #define GEORECT_H

 #include <iomanip>
 #include <fstream>
 #include "IGeomObj.h"

 class GeoRect:public IGeomObj
 {
 public:
    virtual void output();
    virtual void area();
    virtual void circumference();
 };

 #endif
```

GeoRect.cpp

```
  #include "GeoRect.h"
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  void GeoRect::output()
  {  
    cout<<"Rectangle Area: "<<this->f<<" Circumference: "<<this->u;
  };

  void GeoRect::area()
  {
  this->f=this->h*this->b;
  };

  void IGeomObj::circumference()
   {
     this->u=2*this->h+2*this->b;
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your GeoRect.cpp file implements `IGeomObj::circumference()`, which is legal as you can provide an implementation for a pure virtual function.

However this is not sufficient are you're not also implementing `GeoRect::circumference()`, which is required on account of the base class function being declared as a pure virtual function.

Answer (score 0):

In GeoRect.cpp you have a definition for `IGeomObj::circumference`.

```
void IGeomObj::circumference()
{
   this->u=2*this->h+2*this->b;
};
```

but this should be a definition for GeoRect instead.

```
void GeoRect::circumference()
{
   this->u=2*this->h+2*this->b;
};
```

It's also not necessary to add `this->` for every reference to a member.

```
void GeoRect::circumference()
{
   u=2*h+2*b;
};
```